# Autoinstall dependencies in RStudio

Tags: r, installation, error, mapview

Is there any way to autoinstall the packages another package depends on. I just downloaded RStudio 1.3.62 and can't remember having these issues before. They looked like this when I tried to install `mapview`:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘systemfonts’
* removing ‘/home/robin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/systemfonts’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘systemfonts’ is not available for package ‘gdtools’
* removing ‘/home/robin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/gdtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gdtools’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gdtools’ is not available for package ‘svglite’
* removing ‘/home/robin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/svglite’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘svglite’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘svglite’ is not available for package ‘leafpop’
* removing ‘/home/robin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/leafpop’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘leafpop’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘leafpop’, ‘svglite’ are not available for package ‘mapview’
* removing ‘/home/robin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mapview’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mapview’ had non-zero exit status
```

I could install them manually. But then they depend on other packages which I had to install again. Any idea how I can stop this recursive process?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `devtools::update_packages()` which will track down and install dependencies.